# FB Connect wont work on certain devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

So here's a weird one, in one of my apps i have this FB login code:

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"user_friends ", @"user_likes", @"email", @"user_birthday"]
                        handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                            if (error) {
                                // Process error
                                NSLog(@"error in opening facebook session - %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                handler(NO, nil, error);
                            }else if (result.isCancelled){
                                // Handle cancellations
                                handler(NO, nil, error);
                            }else{
                                // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
                                // should check if specific permissions missing
                                FBSDKAccessToken *token = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];
                                handler(YES, token.tokenString, nil);
                            }
                        }];
```

Some of my Beta users have been complaining that the app crashes once they click on the FB login button. I have check my Analytics services and i can see that it is ture.

Now the problem arises here, i have logged in (with my device) into one of my Beta testers FB account to debug this, but for some reason the FB connect works good.

Does any one have any advice or this may have happened to someone?

Thanks